# how to spread out buttons, they are currently stacked?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of buttons on my page, my html is like:

```
<div>
  <input ..>
  <input ...>
</dvi>
```

They are currently just stacking up on each other, I want them all on one horizontal line spread out.

I tried doing:

display:inline

on the outer div, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Try `display:inline` or `float:left` on the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just [float](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-float) them!

```
<div>
   <input style="float: right" />
   <input style="float: right" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div input {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

... or something similar. You could give the inputs classes or IDs (which is generally recommended) so you can apply specific styles to each one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you say you applied inline to the div? That sets the div to display inline, but I think what you want is for the inputs to display inline. try:

```
div input {
display: inline;
}
```

Better?